# Kendo grid with numerictextbox tab out issues

Tags: kendo-grid, kendonumerictextbox

I have a Kendo grid that I am using in a time entry application.  The time entry covers a 2 week pay period, so I have 14 columns where the user can enter the number of hours worked each day for the given task.  I also have columns for the task, an overtime indicator, totals for each week and a total for the pay period.  For the time entry cells I am using a numeric text box.  Each task is a row in the grid.  I have the grid set to `navigatable: true`, so the user can tab from one cell to the next.  This works great until the user enters time in the cell.  When they tab out after entering or changing the value in the time cell they are thrown to the first row and first cell of the grid.  I have tried all kinds of things to get the current cell and force it to move to the next cell on tab, but nothing works.  I am always taken to the first cell in the grid.  Is this a known issue with the Kendo grid when using the numeric text box within the cells?  Or am I doing something wrong here?  Any input would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
        GetTimeSheet: function () {

             function editNumberWithoutSpinners(container, options) {
                $('<input data-text-field="' + options.field + '" ' +
                        'data-value-field="' + options.field + '" ' +
                        'data-bind="value:' + options.field + '" ' +
                        'data-format="' + options.format + '"/>')
                        .appendTo(container)
                        .kendoNumericTextBox({
                            min: 0,
                            max: 25,
                            spinners: false
                        });
                //Select text on focus
                $('.k-input').on('focus', function () { var input = $(this); setTimeout(function () { input.select(); }); });

            }

            //Employee grid
            var timeSheetGrid = $("#Time-Sheet-grid").empty().kendoGrid({
                autoBind: true,
                dataSource: {
                    serverPaging: true,
                    serverSorting: true,
                    serverFiltering: true,
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            url: "/TimeSheet/GetTimeSheetSummary",
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            type: 'POST'
                        },
                        parameterMap: function (data, operation) {
                            return kendo.stringify({
                                employeeNum: JARS.TimeSheet.employeeNumHold,
                                payPeriod: JARS.TimeSheet.payPeriodHold
                            });
                        }
                    },
                    schema: {
                        data: "TimesheetSummaryList",
                        model: {
                            id: "EmployeeNum",
                            fields: {
                                EmployeeNum: { type: "integer", hidden: true },
                                ErrorMessage: { type: "string", editable: false },
                                FullName: { type: "string", editable: false },
                                RCN: { type: "string", editable: false },
                                OtAllowedInd: { type: "string", editable: false },
                                PayPeriodDate: { type: "date", editable: false },
                                HoursDay1: { type: "double", editable: false },
                                HoursDay2: { type: "double", editable: false },
                                HoursDay3: { type: "double", editable: false },
                                HoursDay4: { type: "double", editable: false },
                                HoursDay5: { type: "double", editable: false },
                                HoursDay6: { type: "double", editable: false },
                                HoursDay7: { type: "double", editable: false },
                                Week1Total: { type: "double", editable: false },
                                HoursDay8: { type: "double", editable: false },
                                HoursDay9: { type: "double", editable: false },
                                HoursDay10: { type: "double", editable: false },
                                HoursDay11: { type: "double", editable: false },
                                HoursDay12: { type: "double", editable: false },
                                HoursDay13: { type: "double", editable: false },
                                HoursDay14: { type: "double", editable: false },
                                Week2Total: { type: "double", editable: false },
                                PayPeriodTotal: { type: "double", editable: false },
                                OTHoursDay1: { type: "double", editable: false },
                                OTHoursDay2: { type: "double", editable: false },
                                OTHoursDay3: { type: "double", editable: false },
                                OTHoursDay4: { type: "double", editable: false },
                                OTHoursDay5: { type: "double", editable: false },
                                OTHoursDay6: { type: "double", editable: false },
                                OTHoursDay7: { type: "double", editable: false },
                                OTWeek1Total: { type: "double", editable: false },
                                OTHoursDay8: { type: "double", editable: false },
                                OTHoursDay9: { type: "double", editable: false },
                                OTHoursDay10: { type: "double", editable: false },
                                OTHoursDay11: { type: "double", editable: false },
                                OTHoursDay12: { type: "double", editable: false },
                                OTHoursDay13: { type: "double", editable: false },
                                OTHoursDay14: { type: "double", editable: false },
                                OTWeek2Total: { type: "double", editable: false },
                                OTPayPeriodTotal: { type: "double", editable: false }
                            }
                        },
                        total: function (response) {
                            return $(response.TimesheetList).length
                        }
                    }
                },
                pageable: false,
                sortable: false,
                filterable: false,
                navigatable: true,
                batch: true,
                detailInit: detailInit,
                dataBound: function () {
                    if (JARS.TimeSheet.modeHold == "I") {
                        this.expandRow(this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row").first());
                    }
                },

                columns: [
                    { field: "EmployeeNum", title: "", hidden: true},
                    {
                        field: "FullName", title: "Timesheet for", width: "200px", template: function (data) {
                            var fieldData = data.FullName;
                            if (data.ErrorMessage != "") {
                                fieldData += "<br/><span class='OT_data'>";
                                fieldData += data.ErrorMessage.replace(/\n/g, "<br/>");
                                fieldData += "</span>";
                            }
                            return fieldData;
                        }
                    },
                    { title: "", template: "RT<br/><span class='OT_data'>OT</span>", width: "55px" },
                    { field: "HoursDay1", headerTemplate: '<span>Sat<br/>' + getDay(1) + '</span>', template: "#:data.HoursDay1# <br/><span class='OT_data'> #:data.OTHoursDay1#</span>", width: "55px" },
                    { field: "HoursDay2", headerTemplate: '<span>Sun<br/>' + getDay(2) + '</span>' , template: "#:data.HoursDay2# <br/><span class='OT_data'> #:data.OTHoursDay2#</span>", width: "55px" },
                    { field: "HoursDay3", headerTemplate: '<span>Mon<br/>' + getDay(3) + '</span>', template: "#:data.HoursDay3# <br/><span class='OT_data'> #:data.OTHoursDay3#</span>", width: "55px" },
                    { field: "HoursDay4", headerTemplate: '<span>Tue<br/>' + getDay(4) + '</span>', template: "#:data.HoursDay4# <br/><span class='OT_data'> #:data.OTHoursDay4#</span>", width: "55px" },
                    { field: "HoursDay5", headerTemplate: '<span>Wed<br/>' + getDay(5) + '</span>', template: "#:data.HoursDay5# <br/><span class='OT_data'> #:data.OTHoursDay5#</span>", width: "55px" },
                    { field: "HoursDay6", headerTemplate: '<span>Thur<br/>' + getDay(6) + '</span>', template: "#:data.HoursDay6# <br/><span class='OT_data'> #:data.OTHoursDay6#</span>", width: "55px" },
                    { field: "HoursDay7", headerTemplate: '<span>Fri<br/>' + getDay(7) + '</span>', template: "#:data.HoursDay7# <br/><span class='OT_data'> #:data.OTHoursDay7#</span>", width: "55px" },
                    { headerTemplate: '<span>Week<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;1<br/>Total</span>', template: "#:data.Week1Total# <br/><span class='OT_data'> #:data.OTWeek1Total#</span>", width: "55px" },
                    { field: "HoursDay8", headerTemplate: '<span>Sat<br/>' + getDay(8) + '</span>', template: "#:data.HoursDay8# <br/><span class='OT_data'> #:data.OTHoursDay8#</span>", width: "55px" },
                    { field: "HoursDay9", headerTemplate: '<span>Sun<br/>' + getDay(9) + '</span>', template: "#:data.HoursDay9# <br/><span class='OT_data'> #:data.OTHoursDay9#</span>", width: "55px" },
                    { field: "HoursDay10", headerTemplate: '<span>Mon<br/>' + getDay(10) + '</span>', template: "#:data.HoursDay10# <br/><span class='OT_data'> #:data.OTHoursDay10#</span>", width: "55px" },
                    { field: "HoursDay11", headerTemplate: '<span>Tue<br/>' + getDay(11) + '</span>', template: "#:data.HoursDay11# <br/><span class='OT_data'> #:data.OTHoursDay11#</span>", width: "55px" },
                    { field: "HoursDay12", headerTemplate: '<span>Wed<br/>' + getDay(12) + '</span>', template: "#:data.HoursDay12# <br/><span class='OT_data'> #:data.OTHoursDay12#</span>", width: "55px" },
                    { field: "HoursDay13", headerTemplate: '<span>Thur<br/>' + getDay(13) + '</span>', template: "#:data.HoursDay13# <br/><span class='OT_data'> #:data.OTHoursDay13#</span>", width: "55px" },
                    { field: "HoursDay14", headerTemplate: '<span>Fri<br/>' + getDay(14) + '</span>', template: "#:data.HoursDay14# <br/><span class='OT_data'> #:data.OTHoursDay14#</span>", width: "55px" },
                    { field: "Week2Total", headerTemplate: '<span>Week<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;2<br/>Total</span>', template: "#:data.Week2Total# <br/><span class='OT_data'> #:data.OTWeek2Total#</span>", width: "55px" },
                    { field: "PayPeriodTotal", title: "Total", template: "#:data.PayPeriodTotal# <br/><span class='OT_data'> #:data.OTPayPeriodTotal#</span>", width: "55px" }

                ],
                resizable: true,
            });

            //Time Records
            function detailInit(e) {
                childTimesheetGrid = $("<div/>").appendTo(e.detailCell).kendoGrid({
                    dataSource: {
                        serverPaging: false,
                        serverSorting: false,
                        serverFiltering: false,
                        transport: {
                            read: {
                                url: "/TimeSheet/GetTimeSheets",
                                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                type: 'POST'
                            },
                            update: {
                                url: "/TimeSheet/UpdateTimesheet",
                                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                type: 'POST',
                                complete: function (e) {
                                    $("#Time-Sheet-grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
                                }
                            },
                            destroy: {
                                url: "/TimeSheet/DeleteTimesheet",
                                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                type: 'POST',
                                complete: function (e) {
                                    $("#Time-Sheet-grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
                                }
                            },
                            create: {
                                url: "/TimeSheet/CreateTimesheet",
                                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                type: 'POST',
                                complete: function (e) {
                                    $("#Time-Sheet-grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
                                }
                            },
                            parameterMap: function(data, operation) {
                                if (operation == "read") {
                                    return kendo.stringify({ employeeNum: e.data.EmployeeNum, payPeriod: e.data.PayPeriodDate });
                                }
                                else {
                                    if (operation !== "destroy") {
                                        return kendo.stringify({ model: data });
                                    }
                                    return kendo.stringify({ id: data.TimesheetId });
                                }

                            }
                        },
                        schema: {
                            data: "TimesheetList",
                            model: {
                                id: "TimesheetId",
                                fields: {
                                    Activity: { type: "string", editable: false },
                                    ActvyComments: { type: "string", editable: true },
                                    ActvyLongDesc: { type: "string", editable: false },
                                    OvertimeInd: { type: "string", editable: false },
                                    HoursDay1: { type: "number", editable: true },
                                    HoursDay2: { type: "number", editable: true },
                                    HoursDay3: { type: "number", editable: true },
                                    HoursDay4: { type: "number", editable: true },
                                    HoursDay5: { type: "number", editable: true },
                                    HoursDay6: { type: "number", editable: true },
                                    HoursDay7: { type: "number", editable: true },
                                    HoursDay8: { type: "number", editable: true },
                                    HoursDay9: { type: "number", editable: true },
                                    HoursDay10: { type: "number", editable: true },
                                    HoursDay11: { type: "number", editable: true },
                                    HoursDay12: { type: "number", editable: true },
                                    HoursDay13: { type: "number", editable: true },
                                    HoursDay14: { type: "number", editable: true },
                                    SpreadInd: { type: "string", editable: false },
                                    TimesheetId: { type: "integer", editable: false, nullable: true },
                                    WorkId: { type: "integer", editable: false },
                                    RCN: { type: "string", editable: false },
                                    OtAllowedInd: { type: "string", editable: false },
                                    EmployeeNum: { type: "integer", editable: false },
                                    FullName: { type: "string", editable: false },
                                    PayPeriodDate: { type: "date", editable: false },
                                    Week1Total: {type: "double", editable: false },
                                    Week2Total: { type: "double", editable: false },
                                    PayPeriodTotal: { type: "double", editable: false }
                                }
                            },
                            total: function (response) {
                                return $(response.TimesheetList).length
                            }
                        },
                        group: {
                            field: "FullName", template: "Timesheet for", aggregates: [
                               { field: "HoursDay1", aggregate: "sum" },
                               { field: "HoursDay2", aggregate: "sum" },
                               { field: "HoursDay3", aggregate: "sum" },
                               { field: "HoursDay4", aggregate: "sum" },
                               { field: "HoursDay5", aggregate: "sum" },
                               { field: "HoursDay6", aggregate: "sum" },
                               { field: "HoursDay7", aggregate: "sum" },
                               { field: "HoursDay8", aggregate: "sum" },
                               { field: "HoursDay9", aggregate: "sum" },
                               { field: "HoursDay10", aggregate: "sum" },
                               { field: "HoursDay11", aggregate: "sum" },
                               { field: "HoursDay12", aggregate: "sum" },
                               { field: "HoursDay13", aggregate: "sum" },
                               { field: "HoursDay14", aggregate: "sum" },
                               { field: "Week1Total", aggregate: "sum" },
                               { field: "Week2Total", aggregate: "sum" },
                               { field: "PayPeriodTotal", aggregate: "sum" }
                            ]
                        },
                        aggregate: [{ field: "HoursDay1", aggregate: "sum" },
                               { field: "HoursDay2", aggregate: "sum" },
                               { field: "HoursDay3", aggregate: "sum" },
                               { field: "HoursDay4", aggregate: "sum" },
                               { field: "HoursDay5", aggregate: "sum" },
                               { field: "HoursDay6", aggregate: "sum" },
                               { field: "HoursDay7", aggregate: "sum" },
                               { field: "HoursDay8", aggregate: "sum" },
                               { field: "HoursDay9", aggregate: "sum" },
                               { field: "HoursDay10", aggregate: "sum" },
                               { field: "HoursDay11", aggregate: "sum" },
                               { field: "HoursDay12", aggregate: "sum" },
                               { field: "HoursDay13", aggregate: "sum" },
                               { field: "HoursDay14", aggregate: "sum" },
                               { field: "Week1Total", aggregate: "sum" },
                               { field: "Week2Total", aggregate: "sum" },
                               { field: "PayPeriodTotal", aggregate: "sum" }
                        ]
                    },
                    batch: true,
                    pageable: false,
                    sortable: true,
                    filterable: false,
                    navigatable: true,
                    columns: [
                        { field: "Activity", title: "Activity", width: 190, attributes: { tip: "#:data.ActvyLongDesc#" } },
                        { field: "ActvyComments", title: "Comments", width: 70 },
                        { title: "OT", width: 35, template: "#:data.OvertimeInd=='Y'?'OT':''#" },
                        { field: "HoursDay1", editor: editNumberWithoutSpinners, headerTemplate: '<span>Sat<br/>' + getDay(1) + '</span>', width: 35, template: "#:data.HoursDay1==0?'':data.HoursDay1#", groupFooterTemplate: "#=sum#", attributes: { class: "editable-cell" } },
                        { field: "HoursDay2", editor: editNumberWithoutSpinners, headerTemplate: '<span>Sun<br/>' + getDay(2) + '</span>', width: 35, template: "#:data.HoursDay2==0?'':data.HoursDay2#", groupFooterTemplate: "#=sum#", attributes: { class: "editable-cell" } },
                        { field: "HoursDay3", editor: editNumberWithoutSpinners, headerTemplate: '<span>Mon<br/>' + getDay(3) + '</span>', width: 35, template: "#:data.HoursDay3==0?'':data.HoursDay3#", groupFooterTemplate: "#=sum#", attributes: { class: "editable-cell" } },
                        { field: "HoursDay4", editor: editNumberWithoutSpinners, headerTemplate: '<span>Tue<br/>' + getDay(4) + '</span>', width: 35, template: "#:data.HoursDay4==0?'':data.HoursDay4#", groupFooterTemplate: "#=sum#", attributes: { class: "editable-cell" } },
                        { field: "HoursDay5", editor: editNumberWithoutSpinners, headerTemplate: '<span>Wed<br/>' + getDay(5) + '</span>', width: 35, template: "#:data.HoursDay5==0?'':data.HoursDay5#", groupFooterTemplate: "#=sum#", attributes: { class: "editable-cell" } },
                        { field: "HoursDay6", editor: editNumberWithoutSpinners, headerTemplate: '<span>Thur<br/>' + getDay(6) + '</span>', width: 35, template: "#:data.HoursDay6==0?'':data.HoursDay6#", groupFooterTemplate: "#=sum#", attributes: { class: "editable-cell" } },
                        { field: "HoursDay7", editor: editNumberWithoutSpinners, headerTemplate: '<span>Fri<br/>' + getDay(7) + '</span>', width: 35, template: "#:data.HoursDay7==0?'':data.HoursDay7#", groupFooterTemplate: "#=sum#", attributes: { class: "editable-cell" } },
                        { field: "Week1Total", headerTemplate: '<span>Week<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;1<br/>Total</span>', width: 50, template: "#= HoursDay1 + HoursDay2 +  HoursDay3 + HoursDay4 + HoursDay5 + HoursDay6 + HoursDay7#", 
                        groupFooterTemplate: function (data) {
                            return (data["HoursDay1"].sum + data["HoursDay2"].sum + data["HoursDay3"].sum + data["HoursDay4"].sum + data["HoursDay5"].sum + data["HoursDay6"].sum + data["HoursDay7"].sum);
                        }
                        },
                        { field: "HoursDay8", editor: editNumberWithoutSpinners, headerTemplate: '<span>Sat<br/>' + getDay(8) + '</span>', width: 35, template: "#:data.HoursDay8==0?'':data.HoursDay8#", groupFooterTemplate: "#=sum#", attributes: { class: "editable-cell" } },
                        { field: "HoursDay9", editor: editNumberWithoutSpinners, headerTemplate: '<span>Sun<br/>' + getDay(9) + '</span>', width: 35, template: "#:data.HoursDay9==0?'':data.HoursDay9#", groupFooterTemplate: "#=sum#", attributes: { class: "editable-cell" } },
                        { field: "HoursDay10", editor: editNumberWithoutSpinners, headerTemplate: '<span>Mon<br/>' + getDay(10) + '</span>', width: 35, template: "#:data.HoursDay10==0?'':data.HoursDay10#", groupFooterTemplate: "#=sum#", attributes: { class: "editable-cell" } },
                        { field: "HoursDay11", editor: editNumberWithoutSpinners, headerTemplate: '<span>Tue<br/>' + getDay(11) + '</span>', width: 35, template: "#:data.HoursDay11==0?'':data.HoursDay11#", groupFooterTemplate: "#=sum#", attributes: { class: "editable-cell" } },
                        { field: "HoursDay12", editor: editNumberWithoutSpinners, headerTemplate: '<span>Wed<br/>' + getDay(12) + '</span>', width: 35, template: "#:data.HoursDay12==0?'':data.HoursDay12#", groupFooterTemplate: "#=sum#", attributes: { class: "editable-cell" } },
                        { field: "HoursDay13", editor: editNumberWithoutSpinners, headerTemplate: '<span>Thur<br/>' + getDay(13) + '</span>', width: 35, template: "#:data.HoursDay13==0?'':data.HoursDay13#", groupFooterTemplate: "#=sum#", attributes: { class: "editable-cell" } },
                        { field: "HoursDay14", editor: editNumberWithoutSpinners, headerTemplate: '<span>Fri<br/>' + getDay(14) + '</span>', width: 35, template: "#:data.HoursDay14==0?'':data.HoursDay14#", groupFooterTemplate: "#=sum#", attributes: { class: "editable-cell" } },
                        {field: "Week2Total", headerTemplate: '<span>Week<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;2<br/>Total</span>', width: 50, template: "#= HoursDay8 + HoursDay9 +  HoursDay10 + HoursDay11 + HoursDay12 + HoursDay13 + HoursDay14#",
                        groupFooterTemplate: function (data) {
                            return (data["HoursDay8"].sum + data["HoursDay9"].sum + data["HoursDay10"].sum + data["HoursDay11"].sum + data["HoursDay12"].sum + data["HoursDay13"].sum + data["HoursDay14"].sum);
                        }
                        },
                        {field: "PayPeriodTotal", title: "Total", width: 50, template: "#=  HoursDay1 + HoursDay2 +  HoursDay3 + HoursDay4 + HoursDay5 + HoursDay6 + HoursDay7 + HoursDay8 + HoursDay9 +  HoursDay10 + HoursDay11 + HoursDay12 + HoursDay13 + HoursDay14#",
                        groupFooterTemplate: function (data) {
                            return (data["HoursDay1"].sum + data["HoursDay2"].sum + data["HoursDay3"].sum + data["HoursDay4"].sum + data["HoursDay5"].sum + data["HoursDay6"].sum + data["HoursDay7"].sum +
                            data["HoursDay8"].sum + data["HoursDay9"].sum + data["HoursDay10"].sum + data["HoursDay11"].sum + data["HoursDay12"].sum + data["HoursDay13"].sum + data["HoursDay14"].sum);
                        }
                        }],
                    resizable: true,
                    editable: true,
                    toolbar: toolbarTemplate(e.data.EmployeeNum, e.data.FullName, e.data.RCN, e.data.OtAllowedInd),
                    dataBound: function () {
                        //Set row color when the row is Overtime
                        var grid = childTimesheetGrid;
                        var data = grid.dataSource.data();
                        $.each(data, function (i, row) {
                            if (row.OvertimeInd == 'Y')
                                $('tr[data-uid="' + row.uid + '"] ').css("color", "#FF0000");
                        });

                        //Set background color for weekend columns
                        $('tr').each(function () {
                            $(this).find('td:nth-child(5)').addClass('Weekend_Days');
                            $(this).find('td:nth-child(6)').addClass('Weekend_Days');
                            $(this).find('td:nth-child(13)').addClass('Weekend_Days');
                            $(this).find('td:nth-child(14)').addClass('Weekend_Days');
                        });
                    },
                    save: function (e) {
                        var dataSource = this.dataSource;
                        e.model.one("change", function () {
                            dataSource.one("change", function () {
                                dataSource.aggregates().HoursDay1.sum;
                                dataSource.aggregates().HoursDay2.sum;
                                dataSource.aggregates().HoursDay3.sum;
                                dataSource.aggregates().HoursDay4.sum;
                                dataSource.aggregates().HoursDay5.sum;
                                dataSource.aggregates().HoursDay6.sum;
                                dataSource.aggregates().HoursDay7.sum;
                                dataSource.aggregates().HoursDay8.sum;
                                dataSource.aggregates().HoursDay9.sum;
                                dataSource.aggregates().HoursDay10.sum;
                                dataSource.aggregates().HoursDay11.sum;
                                dataSource.aggregates().HoursDay12.sum;
                                dataSource.aggregates().HoursDay13.sum;
                                dataSource.aggregates().HoursDay14.sum;
                                dataSource.aggregates().Week1Total.sum;
                                dataSource.aggregates().Week2Total.sum;
                                dataSource.aggregates().PayPeriodTotal.sum;
                            });
                            dataSource.fetch();
                        });
                    }

                }).data("kendoGrid");

                childTimesheetGrid.table.kendoTooltip({
                    filter: "td[tip]",
                    content: function (e) {
                        var target = e.target; // element for which the tooltip is shown
                        return $(target).attr('tip');
                    }
                });
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally found a fix.
Found the tabbing was not working due to the save of the weekly and daily subtotals (my aggregates).  So I allow the save and then refocus to the next cell if the user clicks tab.

Here is my solution:
Added two variable to hold my location and if I clicked tab:

```
JARS.TimeSheet.focusCellHold = -1;
JARS.TimeSheet.isKeyTabHold = false;
```

Then added this code to the grid's databound event:

```
if (JARS.TimeSheet.focusCellHold > 0 && JARS.TimeSheet.isKeyTabHold) {
    setTimeout(function () {

        var grid = childTimesheetGrid;
        //Set the focus on the next cell.
        grid.current(grid.tbody.find("td").eq(JARS.TimeSheet.focusCellHold + 1));
        grid.editCell(grid.tbody.find("td").eq(JARS.TimeSheet.focusCellHold + 1));
        JARS.TimeSheet.isKeyTabHold = false;
    }, 750);
}

$(childTimesheetGrid.tbody).on("keydown", "td", function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === kendo.keys.TAB) {
        JARS.TimeSheet.isKeyTabHold = true;
    }
});

$(childTimesheetGrid.tbody).on("focus", "td", function (e) {
    var cell = $(this).closest("td");
    var cellIndx = $("td", childTimesheetGrid.tbody).index(cell);
    JARS.TimeSheet.focusCellHold = cellIndx;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of jQuery are you using? I read there were some issues with the numeric boxes with 1.8.2...try updating.

Comment: Referring to this: [link](http://www.telerik.com/forums/tabbing-out-of-numeric-inputs-causes-changed-value-to-revert)

Comment: I am using jQuery 1.91.

Comment: Also noticed that it has issues with my comment cell in the grid.  It also goes back to the beginning of the grid when I edit the comment and tab out.